# C# Creating a Simple Calculator using Stack

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple calculator with an undo function using stack. If anybody can tell me where I went wrong with my code, that would be awesome. It looks like some of my variables were not properly stated, maybe. I have never used stack for coding. I read articles about it but I need help with my code to get to the right direction.

```
 class Calculator
   {
    public Stack<double> result;
    double total;
    public void add(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Sum:{0}", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void sub(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a - b;
        Console.WriteLine("Difference:{0}", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void mul(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a * b;
        Console.WriteLine("Product:{0} ", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void div(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b!=0)
        {
            total = a / b;
            Console.WriteLine("Quotient:{0}", total);
            result.Push(total);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Cannot divide by 0");
        }
    }
    double getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }
    void undo()
    {
        if (result.DefaultIfEmpty())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UNDO IS NOT AVAILABLE");
        }
        result.Pop();
        total = result.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);
    }
    void clear()
    {
        while (result.DefaultIfEmpty())
            result.Pop();
        total = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);
    }
    int main()
    {
        Calculator cal;
        string line;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter (Clear, Undo, Exit, Expression):");

            if (line == "Exit")
                break;
            else if (line == "Undo")
                cal.undo();
            else if (line == "Clear")
                cal.clear();
            else
            {
                double a, b;

                char c;

                if (c == '+')
                    cal.add(a, b);
                if (c == '-')
                    cal.sub(a, b);
                if (c == '*')
                    cal.mul(a, b);
                if (c == '/')
                    cal.div(a, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged this?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has several problems,

1. The most important of all is you are not initializing any of the variables (result, cal, line, a, b, c) c# needs to know what values they have in order to be able to do something with them. Fixing that seems to make your calculator work.
2. Second thing, you should take the line the user input (Something I added) and convert it to lower characters, so no matter how your writes Clear, Undo Or Exit works
3. About the expression you need there to initialize the variables (I added something too)
4. The main has to be static, take that into account whenever you program a c# console app

I ll leave you the code fixed to work, try to play with it, and understand what I did, if you have any questions feel free to leave a commment

```
class Calculator
{
    public Stack<double> result = new Stack<double>();
    double total;
    public void add(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Sum:{0}", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void sub(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a - b;
        Console.WriteLine("Difference:{0}", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void mul(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a * b;
        Console.WriteLine("Product:{0} ", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void div(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b != 0)
        {
            total = a / b;
            Console.WriteLine("Quotient:{0}", total);
            result.Push(total);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Cannot divide by 0");
        }
    }
    double getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }
    void undo()
    {
        if (result.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UNDO IS NOT AVAILABLE");
        }
        result.Pop();
        total = result.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);
    }
    void clear()
    {
        while (result.Count != 0)
            result.Pop();
        total = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);
    }
    static int Main()
    {
        Calculator cal = new Calculator();
        string line = "";
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter (Clear, Undo, Exit, Expression):");
            line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (line.ToLower() == "exit")
                break;
            else if (line.ToLower() == "undo")
                cal.undo();
            else if (line.ToLower() == "clear")
                cal.clear();
            else
            {
                double a, b;
                char c;

                Console.WriteLine("Write the first number");
                double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a);

                Console.WriteLine("Write the second number");
                double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b);

                Console.WriteLine("Write the operand (+,-,/,*)");
                char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out c);


                if (c == '+')
                    cal.add(a, b);
                if (c == '-')
                    cal.sub(a, b);
                if (c == '*')
                    cal.mul(a, b);
                if (c == '/')
                    cal.div(a, b);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The Main has to be static, **and must return a value**" this is wrong, you can use void Main.

Comment: If I wanted to add an originator, memento, and caretaker design. Would the code be very different from this or can I just add another class and pass it through?

Comment: Im not familiarized with the memento design pattern, What would you want to save in it?

Comment: The running total

Comment: from what i researched, the memento pattern is to save different states in your program, and you can come back to any of those states. You can implement the memento pattern, but that is kinda the stack you are using here so it would change some code